# Use existing tags on Wordpress front-end posting

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, tags

I have a front end posting to allow users to update their posts. Currently I'm using this to allow entering new tags:

**This is my HTML form:**

```
  <form id="featured_upload" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="new_image_upload" id="new_image_upload"  multiple="false" />
    <input type="text" name="newtags" id="newtags" value="" />
    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="" />
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new_image_upload', 'new_image_upload_nonce' ); ?>
    <input id="submit_new_image_upload" name="submit_new_image_upload" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

**This is part of the code:**

```
    // If the form has been submitted with new tags
    if ( isset( $_POST['newtags'] ) ) {
    // get existing tags
    $post_tags = get_the_tags();
    // concatenates both existing and new tags
    $concatenated_tags = array($post_tags, sanitize_text_field($_POST['newtags']));
   // Add all the tags to the post
    wp_set_post_tags(get_the_ID(), $concatenated_tags , true    );
    }
```

The problem with this is that is creating many unecessary tags on my database and I need my users to see the sugestion of tags already present in my database.

So, I need that `<input type="text" name="newtags" id="newtags" value="" />` make them existing tags sugestions, just like wordpress does on the post editing backend. See the image bellow to check the desired result on my front-end form:

[image: the input field "newtags" must suggest existing tags from the wp database]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Select2 javascript library for the frontend, specifically the automatic tokenization tagging functionality. See here: https://select2.org/tagging#automatic-tokenization-into-tags

Once you have enqued the Select2 file into your frontend you could do something like...

**Your frontend form:**
Note that I have added the `$has_tag` variable which will automatically select all saved tags for the current post. See [`selected()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/selected/)

```php
<?php $post_id = get_the_ID(); ?>
<form id="featured_upload" method="post" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...

    <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="<?= $post_id; ?>">

    <select name="tags" multiple id="frontend-tagger">
        <?php if ( $tags = get_terms( [ 'taxonomy' => 'post_tag', 'hide_empty' => false ] ) ): ?>
            <?php foreach ( $tags as $tag ): ?>
                <?php $has_tag = selected( has_tag( $tag->term_id, $post_id ), true, false ); ?>
                <option value="<?= $tag->name; ?>"<?= $has_tag; ?>><?= $tag->name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        <?php endif ?>
    </select>

    ...
</form>
```

**JS to initiate the select2 field:**

```js
$( '#frontend-tagger' ).select2( {
    tags: true,
    tokenSeparators: [ ',' ]
} );
```

**Saving process:** Note because we are now including already saved tags in the pay load, we do not need to concat existing tags. We can now change the third paramater for `wp_set_post_tags` to `false` as we do not need to append tags.

```php
$post_id = !empty( $_POST[ 'post_id' ] ) : (int)$_POST[ 'post_id' ] : null;

if ( isset( $_POST[ 'tags' ] ) ) {

    // Sanitize array values
    $tags = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', $_POST[ 'tags' ] );

    wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $tags , false );
}
```

The above code hasn't been test, just a starting point for you to work from.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this shows all tags (and I hundreds), which makes this almost impossible to work. What I need is something that makes sugestions as you type in. Like the example above on the picture.